# Integers in ternary operation-GNUplot

Tags: math, integer, gnuplot, ternary-operator, boolean-operations

I try to write a function by parts in GNUplot where f(x) is a constant (floating number) and it just works when the constant is an integer.The error is

> 'non-integer passed to boolean operator'

This is my code:

```
R=53.
R0=40.
rho1=339.7
rho2=383.4
rhom=333.4

f1(x)=x<=R0 ? rho1 : rho2 && x>=R ? rhom : rho2
p f1(x)
```

Could anybody help me with this (most likely) stupid problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on `f1(x)` definition. It has boolean result.
The function

```
f1(x)= (x<=R0 ? rho1 : rho2) && (x>=R ? rhom : rho2)
```

for x=40 returns

```
f1(x)= (true) && (false) -> false
```

which is boolean.

If you would like to plot `rho1` for `x<=R0`, `rho2` for `x in (R0,R)` and `rhom` for `x=>R` then you have to use:

```
f1(x)= (x<=R0 ? rho1 : (x>=R ? rhom : rho2) )
p [20:80] f1(x)
```

[image]